# Apply Perl RegExp to Remove Parenthesis and Text at End of String

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which includes parenthesis with text inside the parenthesis.  How do I remove the parenthesis with text at the end of the string while keeping the other words in string?

Input:

```
   Potatoes Rice (Meat)
```

Output:

```
   Potatoes Rice
```

My code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

my $noparenthesis = "Potatoes Rice (Meat)";
$noparenthesis =~ s/^/$1/gi;
say $noparenthesis;
```

Comment: use `$noparenthesis =~ s/\(.*$//g` do you have any other words in parenthesis??

Comment: I suggest you look over the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), or a regex tutorial from a good book.

Comment: Alright, I seemed so. It will be _much_ easier to first read over a topic, in particular when it comes to regex.  It's a mini-language, and while you can start using it effectively with very little there is a structure and rules to it.  Not knowing those basics makes it _much_ harder.

Comment: @Onyambu: No: that's very misleading. All your pattern does is remove *everything* from the first opening parenthesis to the end of the string. That's not what was asked for.

Comment: @Borodin it seems thats how Op’s data was stuctured. Anyway there can be various things to look at. And i did address them in the comment section of the answer i provided

Comment: @Onyambu: *"it seems thats how Op’s data was stuctured"* The OP's *only example* has a string at the end of the line that they want to remove. It's not appropriate to assume that they will *always* want to remove everything after the first opening parenthesis. Your "answer" should be a comment asking more about the expected format of the data.

Comment: @Borodin Well my answer does include a regex that just delete just the last paranthesis after using a simple regex. I do have that option in the answer.. does that not satisfy you? Well, if at all my answer seems not to answer the question at hand, please go ahead and provide an answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use warnings;

my $noparenthesis = "Potatoes Rice (Meat)";
$noparenthesis =~ s/\(.*$//g;
say $noparenthesis;
```

If there are other words in parenthesis that you would like to keep since they are not in the end of the sentence then you can use the expression:

```
 $noparenthesis =~ s/\s*\([^()]+\)\s*$//g;
```

This will only delete the parenthesis at the end of the string, and possible trailing spaces, as well as spaces preceding them (so no trailing spaces stay in the string). Since `(` and `)` characters are disallowed inside the matched parentheses, by the negated character class, this won't match nested parentheses, should the string have that.

Comment: Now this will not touch nested parens, what is probably OK for the purpose but it is good to mention.  Also, how about allowing spaces next to parens?

Comment: @zim, if I were to complicate things, then I could use `(\(([^()]*)(?:(?1)(?2))*\))$` which will take  everything you want into consideration

Comment: Yeah, it gets messier ... i didn't mean to suggest complicating things, but only perhaps mentioning restrictions, special cases if any, etc.  I would add `\s*` where suitable as that is a simple and realistic possiblity that can throw it off.

Comment: @zdim gotcha. Will take that into consideration. I hope `(\(([^()]*)(?:(?1)(?2))*\))$` does solve everything though

Comment: @zim but `\s*` is part of `[^()]*` so why include it?

Comment: While it seems unneeded here, the question of nested delims is anything but simple -- really need be specified as a separate requirement (what to do if there is nesting). That may, or may not, also be suitable to (just) mention.  Such basic questions are hard to gauge right because of so many cases and contexts of all kinds.  I am not suggesting to expand!

Comment: after the closing paren `\)\s*$`.  Then, do we want to leave trailing spaces?  Probably not, so `\s*\(` as well

Comment: @Onyambu: Please don't write half-answers and solicit edits in the comments. Any answer you write should be complete and demonstrably correct.

Comment: @Onyambu: *"read through the comments before you downvote"* That is very rude, and I shouldn't have to read through comments. An answer should be *demonstrably correct* and *self-contained*. You're not posting on a chat forum here.

Comment: @Borodin. Usually a simple regex is required depending on the structure of the data. Why complecate things when just a simple regex can work? According to Op’s data structure, the provided solition will work.. and it is the most simplified solution. We only complecate things to take ito consideration all the conditions required.

Comment: @Onyambu: *"Usually a simple regex is required depending on the structure of the data"* That doesn't really say anything. Sometimes a simple pattern will suffice, and other times it must be more complex. Since you have never seen the OP's real data you have no idea what is appropriate. It's very likely that *"all the conditions required"* aren't part of the question.

Comment: @Borodin in that case OP woukd not have accepted the answer before even i edited it

Comment: @Onyambu: "Lucking out" isn't a responsible software development tactic.

Comment: Edited, and added a comment about nested parens; please test such a case, for instance with:  `word (with (nested) parens)`.  If you don't like it please by all means roll it back :)

Comment: @zdim `(\(([^()]*)(?:(?1)(?2))*\))\s*$` can be used to delete the last parenthesis whether nested or not

Comment: How about more levels of nesting? Then, once you reach for a module to deal with the serious problem of nested delims -- do we want to blow away all of it, or just the outer ones -- or just the inner ones? But, do we want to touch that in the first place?  That's why I said that there should be a requirement specifying this.  In this case, it seems that the OP has in their data a parenthetical remark of some sort and a simple solution is likely suitable. Still, nested parens could just happen with any such data so I suggested leaving a note on it.

Comment: @Onyambu: I agree with **zdim** (please stop calling him "zim"): there is no way of writing an answer until you know the full requirements. All of this should have been established in comments on the question, but you chose to escalate it by publishing your guess as an *answer*, which it doesn't deserve.

Comment: Let's elaborate our guessing game a little more.  Imagine the OP comes along and says "_well, a pair of parens at the end goes, no matter what's inside_".  OK, so ... `\(.*\)\s*$` ? ... well, **no** -- that would match from the _first_ `(` in the string since `.*` is greedy. It may also backtrack a lot.  It's actually not so simple.  I think that it's "OK" (to an extent) to pick a simple and perhaps obvious case in a question like this, but then we should absolutely also state kinds of things that are unaccounted for.  That was my point.  This isn't critique, just talking :)